# memcopy vector?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, vector

I have a piece of C code:

```
mel[i] = malloc(sizeof(double)*mellength[i]);           
memcpy(mel[i],&temp[melstart[i]],mellength[i]*sizeof(double));
```

I am converting this to C++ and use vectors instead of arrays:

```
vector< vector< double > > mel; // 2D vector

mel[i].resize(mellength[i]);
```

I have an array called "temp" (which is 1D) and I want to copy all the elements from "temp" into the vector mel. I have tried this:

```
for(int k=0; (k < mellength[i]); k++)
{
    mel[i][k] = temp[i];
    cout << mel[i][k] << endl;
}
```

But saldy it does not work, just prints out values that should not be there. I have included the C function, as well as the C++ function below, if you want an in-depth view at what I am trying to do.

C function:

```
void Setup_Mel(int fft_size, int sample_rate) {
    int i,j,k,tap;
    double fmax;
    double dphi;
    double fsample;
    double freq;
    double temp[fft_size/2];

    fmax=2595*log10(8000.0f/700+1);
    dphi = fmax/17;
    freq = (double)sample_rate/fft_size;


    for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
            melstart[i]=fft_size/2;
            mellength[i]=0;
            memset(temp,0,sizeof(double)*fft_size/2);
            for (j=0; j<fft_size/2; j++) {
                    fsample = 2595*log10(freq*j/700 + 1);

                    if ((dphi*i <= fsample) && (fsample < dphi*(i+1))) temp[j] = (fsample-dphi*i)/(dphi*(i+1)-dphi*i);
                    if ((dphi*(i+1) <= fsample) && (fsample < dphi*(i+2))) temp[j] = (fsample-dphi*(i+2))/(dphi*(i+1)-dphi*(i+2));
                    if ((temp[j] != 0) && (melstart[i] > j)) melstart[i] = j;
                    if (temp[j] != 0) mellength[i]++;
            }
            mel[i] = malloc(sizeof(double)*mellength[i]);           
            memcpy(mel[i],&temp[melstart[i]],mellength[i]*sizeof(double));
  //              for (k=0; k<mellength[i]; tap++,k++) printf("mel filter: %d, %d, %d, %f,  %f\n",i,melstart[i]+k,tap,mel[i][k],(melstart[i]+k)*freq);
    }
}
```

C++ Code:

```
void setUp_Mel(int fft_size, int sample_rate, vector< vector< double > > &mel, int *melstart, int *mellength)
{
    double fmax;
    double dphi;
    double fsample;
    double freq;
    double temp[fft_size/2];

fmax = 2595*log10(8000.0f/700+1);
dphi = fmax / 17;
freq = (double)sample_rate/fft_size;

  for(int i=0; (i < 16); i++)
  { 
      melstart[i] = fft_size/2;
      mellength[i] = 0;
      double temp[fft_size/2];
      //double *temp = new double[fft_size/2];

      for(int j=0; (j < fft_size/2); j++)
      {
          fsample = 2595*log10(freq*j/700 + 1);

          if ((dphi*i <= fsample) && (fsample < dphi*(i+1)))
          {
             temp[j] = (fsample-dphi*i)/(dphi*(i+1)-dphi*i);
          }

          if ((dphi*(i+1) <= fsample) && (fsample < dphi*(i+2))) {

              temp[j] = (fsample-dphi*(i+2))/(dphi*(i+1)-dphi*(i+2));
          }

          if ((temp[j] != 0) && (melstart[i] > j))
          {
              melstart[i] = j;
          }

          if (temp[j] != 0) mellength[i]++;

      }
      mel[i].resize(mellength[i]);

      for(int k=0; (k < mellength[i]); k++)
      {
          mel[i] = temp[i];
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: How about first reading the `std::vector` [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? To initialize a vector with the contents of an array use, `std::vector<T> vec( arrayOfT, arrayOfT + numElementsInArrayOfT );`

Comment: Wouldn't that be `mel[i][k] = temp[melstart[i]+k];` instead of `mel[i][k] = temp[i];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure the outer vector has the right size.

```
vector< vector< double > > mel; // 2D vector
mel.resize( numberOfArrays );
```

Then you can use the `assign` member function to do the copying:

```
mel[i].assign( temp, temp + mellength[i] );
```

If this doesn't work, then the vectors are not the problem.

---

Regardless, looking at your C++ function, I don't see the code you posted in the first place.  I see this:

```
  mel[i].resize(mellength[i]);

  for(int k=0; (k < mellength[i]); k++)
  {
      mel[i] = temp[i];
  }
```

Using `i` as the iterator instead of `k` (among other things).  That won't copy the temp array.  It shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int k=0; (k < mellength[i]); k++)
      {
          mel[i] = temp[i];
      }
```

you do absolutely nothing in this loop besides assigning the same value `mel[i]` to the value `temp[i]` k times. My guess is you forgot to use the k variable in the for loop.